# Laravel's Forgot password does nothing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've got a pretty basic "panel" for a game called GTA San Andreas.
My problem is that I can't get the forgot password to work at all, it only reloads the page after I hit the submit button.
I will leave down the controllers and other files.

Reset blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Reset Password</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/password/email') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $email or old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Reset Password
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Email blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<!-- Main Content -->
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Reset Password</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/password/email') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Send Password Reset Link
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

SendsPasswordResetEmails.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

trait SendsPasswordResetEmails
{
    /**
     * Display the form to request a password reset link.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.email');
    }

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['playerEMail' => 'required|email']);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('playerEMail')
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset link.
     *
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetLinkResponse($response)
    {
        return back()->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset link.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return back()->withErrors(
            ['email' => trans($response)]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker();
    }
}
```

Please let me know what may be wrong, the routes are the following:

```
 |        | POST     | password/email                  |                     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest               |
|        | POST     | password/reset                  |                     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest               |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset                  |                     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest               |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token}          |                     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest               |
```

Comment: Have your ran the migrations? `php artisan migrate` to fill the tables used for the password resets

Comment: Have you setup your email settings? AFAIK, that is required.

Comment: Yes, all the tables are there and the email settings are correct, the email confirmation from theyr profile works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reset blade file look at your email input field its name is `email`. But on your controller side you are expecting a `playerEmail`. For confirmation check your `Session` tab's errors variable on your laravel debugbar.

So What is Happening?
you are having a validation error with key `playerEmail` but you are displaying validation errors with key `email`, so no error is being displayed.

You can fix it by simply changing a couple of lines in your controller.

This one:

```
$this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);
```

And this one:

```
$response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
    $request->only('email')
);
```

Now it should work. :)

**TIP:**
If you are using laravel>=5.5, you can call validate method directly on `request`, also it returns the validated data if the validation passes. Here's how you can improve code.

```
$data = $request->validate(['email'] => 'required|email');
$response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink($data['email']);
```

Just in case you are not aware of it.

Comment: The email server is setuped. As I said the other part where you can confirm your email works perfectly.

Comment: The forgot password, only reloads the page when I hit submit

Comment: But this is what expected, all that button does is send an email to the user with a link to reset password. You should check emails, are you getting any emails?

Comment: No emails are being sent, it should show me an alert saying that an email was sent to my address.

Comment: Have you tested your mail setup, there maybe a problem with your mail setup, if you are not getting mails. For the alert part, you should display status message in your blade file...

Comment: The mail setup works perfectly, as for the alert, there's one if the action was completed successfully. I don't know what else to do.
Demo: https://panel.b-gaming.ro/password/reset - debug is on

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using default Laravel Auth Scaffolding, have you tried using

```
{{ route('password.request') }}
```

instead of

```
{{ url('/password/email') }}
```

Comment: Yes I did and still no luck :( Ran out of ideeas.